# Range().Select and error 1004 issues

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fun a selection execution from CoverPage Sheet of a excel workbook. Its intended to select a cell range on the next page and do whatever.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purpose").Range(Cells(48, 1), Cells(48, 9)).Select

With Selection
    .Borders (xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
```

However the code runs when I have the sheet "Purpose" opened. But once I run it from the coverpage it fails. Its something to do with the referencing I guess, however I tried other solutions I could find and it would not work.

Anyhelp is apprciated,
Steven

Comment: Common problems with scope when using the `Select` method. Ways to avoid it: Do not use `Select` unless absolutely necessary. 99% of the time it can be done without it.

Comment: [INTERESTING READ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/excel-macro-avoiding-using-select)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Reading it now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sheet name `Purpose` is not active when you run the macro, you will get an error since Excel cannot `Select` a range on an inactive worksheet.

Revise:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Purpose").Range(Cells(48, 1), Cells(48, 9))
    .Borders (xlEdgeBottom)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
```